# RHEL server Booting problem: "fsck.ext3: unable to resolve 'LABEL=/u01'

Tags: rhel, boot, fsck

We had an old Linux server in the workplace for last few years, so I decided to turn it on and it's showing this problem during boot up:

```
No devices found
Setting up Logical Volume Management.                      [  OK  ]
Checking filesystems
/:         clean,  60514 /  5124480 files, 1177926 /  5120710 blocks
/tmp:      clean,     57 /   524288 files,   25421 /   524112 blocks
/var:      clean,   1477 /   524288 files,   57606 /   524112 blocks
/usr:      clean, 184343 /  1312000 files, 1300834 /  1311297 blocks
/archive:  clean,     24 /  8960896 files,  415210 /  8960253 blocks0
/backup:   clean,     17 / 12812288 files,  478934 / 12799788 blocks
fsck.ext3: Unable to resolve `LABEL=/u01`
/boot1:    clean,     33 /   128520 files,   32789 /   514048 blocks
                                                           [FAILED]

*** An error occurred during the file system check.
*** Dropping you to a shell; the system will reboot
*** when you leave the shell.
Give root password for maintenance
(or type Control-D to continue): EDAC MC0: UE row 0, channel-a= 0 channel-b= 1
labels "-" (Branch=0 DRAM-Bank=0 RDWR=Read RAS=4812 CAS=0 FATAL Err=0x4 
(>Tmid) Thermal event with intelligent throttling disabled))
```

I tried to use `fsck` to check for errors, but I still cannot boot into the OS.

Why is that?

After using `fsck -a` it's showing `fsck.ext3:Unable to resolve 'LABLE=/u01'`.

Output of `cat /etc/fstab`:

```
LABEL=/              /              ext3      defaults          1 1
LABEL=/tmp           /tmp           ext3      defaults          1 2
LABEL=/var           /var           ext3      defaults          1 2
LABEL=/usr           /usr           ext3      defaults          1 2
LABEL=/archive       /archive       ext3      defaults          1 2
LABEL=/backup        /backup        ext3      defaults          1 2
LABEL=/u01           /u01           ext3      defaults          1 2
LABEL=/boot1         /boot          ext3      defaults          1 2
tmpfs                /dev/shm       tmpfs     defaults          0 0
devpts               /dev/pts       devpts    gid=5,mode=620    0 0
sysfs                /sys           sysfs     defaults          0 0
proc                 /proc          proc      defaults          0 0
LABEL=SWAP-sda6      swap           swap      defaults          0 0
```

Comment: Looks like problem with label on one of your partitions. fsck is try to look for partition based on label identifier. Login in recovery mode and fix partitions label in /etc/fstab file.

Comment: well, i have logged in to the /etc/fstab file... i read in a site that i shoud edit some field in the file... which one ???

Comment: if possible provide output of fdisk -l and blkid and cat /etc/fstab. And one more suggestion to you if you are playing with production box and you have no idea what are you doing keep your hands out of it.

Comment: Check this link https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab to know more about how to edit /etc/fstab file.

Comment: If you urgently need access to system. Just comment (#) line that contain 'LABLE=/u01' and restart box. Then try to fix it.

Comment: its not a production box, an old decommissioned box we are trying to salvage. i have put the output screenshot of /etc/fstab on the question... how to edit it ???

Comment: In your server all partitions are mounted with LABEL reference. There are many ways to refer partitions. You can use LABEL, UUID, Device file (/dev/sdx). I will recommend you to just comment out line containing LABEL=/uo1 and restart. Then try to fix it. If possible please provide output of fdisk and blkid. So we can identity which partitions is taged with label /uo1

Comment: i think commenting out can be a solution, but for that i need to open the fstab as writeable right ?? its opening as readonly.. so i guess i need to remount the root ???

Comment: yes you need root (/) partition writable. Try mount -o remount,rw /

Comment: well thanx a ton, it booted up after commenting out the /LABEL/uo1

now, what about the data in that label, is that lost??? i guess its a stupid question, sorry...

Comment: Well you can provide output of fdisk -l, blkid and lsblk. So we can identify which partition/block device is missing. You informed that server is decommissioned. May be device/lun that holds /uo1 is removed and system admin forget to remove entry in /etc/fstab.